# How to improve code to include columns from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a `join` statement for an inventory report of sorts but I am not sure what I am missing.

So I tried doing the reverse of my join statement and some columns remain omitted. I'm just not sure what I should add or change in the code.
My tables look something like this:

```
PRODUCT_TBL: productID|productDescription|stockQuantity

PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL: supplierID|productID|vendorPartID|productCost|purchased Quantity
```

```
select PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL.productID,PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL.vendorPartID,PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL.productCost
from PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL
inner join PRODUCT_TBL on PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL.productID = PRODUCT_TBL.productID
order by productCost desc
```

I expected one other column aside from `productID` to appear in the results but what I got only has information from the `product_supplier_tbl` and the `productID` from `product_supplier_tbl` and `product_tbl`.

Comment: What do you mean, there’s no column from the joined table in the select list?

Comment: I'm not clear… **you** are choosing which columns to get from each table

Comment: I'm really not sure what I should add to the code to get what I wanted from each table. I just need clarification on what I need to do to include ```product_description``` in my join statement.

Comment: just add it to the `SELECT`...`SELECT column1, column2, column3.....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You include any columns - from any of the tables you have joined together - in the SELECT list to return it in your query results.

```
select PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL.productID
,PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL.vendorPartID
,PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL.productCost
,PRODUCT_TBL.product_description --adding a column to the SELECT list
from PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL
inner join PRODUCT_TBL on PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_TBL.productID = PRODUCT_TBL.productID
order by productCost desc
```